# Photoshop CS3 Layer effects - Radial Gradient's center

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, gradient

How do I pick the center point for a radial gradient that has been applied via layer effect to a shape? It's defaulting to the center of my shape but I want the gradient's center point to be near the top of my shape instead. Anyone?

Pics
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1220621/stackxchange1.jpg
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1220621/stackxchange2.jpg

Comment: Despite the fact that your question has been answered, I would like to add in your images, but the links are invalid. If you post new URLs, I'd be happy to add them. Just @ me in the comments if and when you decide to do it. Welcome to the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click and drag the gradient fill into position while the Layer Style dialogue box is still open.

Comment: I first thought about creating a duplicate of the shape as a clipping mask for the original shape, give the clipping mask desired gradient fill effect and move it to the wanted position. Or creating layers from the effects (second-click the effect list -> `Create layers`) and move them about. But this is more elegant and better answer (of which I didn't know of).

Comment: Wow. Thank you! That wasn't very obvious! :-D

Comment: wow thanks, that's so annoying! in CS6 when I dragged the gradient without the gradient dialog open I could see it move then it would jump back when I release the mouse button. confusing!